# Buffer array overflow in for loop in c

Tags: c++, c

When would a program crash in a buffer overrun case

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main() {
    char buff[50];
    int i=0;
    for( i=0; i <100; i++ )
    {
        buff[i] = i;
        printf("buff[%d]=%d\n",i,buff[i]);
    }
}
```

What will happen to first 50 bytes assigned, when would the program crash?

I see in my UBUNTU with gcc a.out it is crashing when i 99

```
>>
buff[99]=99
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
<<
```

I would like to know why this is not crashing when assignment happening at buff[51] in the for loop?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You can never predict **when** (or *if at all*) it crashes, but you **cannot rely** upon it '*not crashing*' and code an application.

**Reasoning**

The rationale is that there is no compile or run time *'index out of bound checking*' in c arrays. That is present in **STL vectors** or arrays in other higher level languages. So whenever your program *accesses memory beyond the allocated range*, it depends whether it *simply corrupts* another field on your program's stack or affects memory of *another program* or something else, so one can never predict a crash which *only occurs in extreme cases*. It only *crashes* in a state that forces the OS to intervene OR when it no longer remains possible for your program to function correctly.

**Example**

Say you were inside a function call, and immediately next to your array was, the RETURN address i.e. the address your program uses to return to the function it was called from. Suppose you corrupted that and now your program tries to return to the corrupted value, which is not a valid address. Hence it would crash in such a situation.

*The worst happens when you silently modified another field's value and didn't even discover what was wrong* assuming no crash occurred.

Comment: Thanks .. Just would like know m why it did not crash when assignment happening at buff[51] in for loop?. is not illegal ?

Comment: I just added the explaination

Comment: Thanks That explains it :)

Comment: No problem - glad i could be of help. It is a good idea to read through 'a program's image in memory'. Helps to learn a lot about program behavior.

Comment: @SureshKandukuru Adding to fayyazkl's answer: "As runtime system detects memory right violation by a process -- An **invalid access** to valid memory gives: SIGSEGV And access to an **invalid address** gives: SIGBUS signals to terminate process"

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan nice addition. I wasn't aware of the precise signals for each case +1

Comment: @fayyazkl Search this words `Macro: int SIGSEGV` and  `Macro: int SIGBUS` read para, @[Signal Handling](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html#SEC358) And this is best resource I found for learning signals in Linux.

Comment: @fayyazkl Additionally You may like to read about `Macro: int SIGFPE` I am sure you will find it interesting (I was wonder that these possible reasons) of-course not related to this post-segfault.

Comment: Thank you i am familiar with the concept and pretty much use several of them. Just wasn't aware which ones are implicitly fired in the particular scenario referenced above. Looking at the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you have allocated on the stack the buffer, the app possibly will crash on the first occasion you overwrite an instruction which is to be executed, possibly somewhere in the code of the for loop... at least that's how it's supposed to be in theory.

Comment: Aren't you assuming that CS (code segment) lies very next to stack)? That might be true in some specific case but not generically. Also i was thinking won't it first over write return address, which is inside the current activation record of function, rather than reaching out to code segment. The concept is right though.+1

Comment: Yes, I assumed :) On all the (archaic) architectures I work(ed) on they are hand in hand.